# How do I require an email address to have an @ and password be over 5 characters but lower than 15

Tags: java, file, email, passwords, output

My current code is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.acl.NotOwnerException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {

    System.out.print("Enter username: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username = scanner.nextLine();


    System.out.print("Enter email: ");
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email = scanner.nextLine();


    System.out.print("Enter password: ");
    Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String password = scanner.nextLine();





    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("passwords.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
{
    out.print(username);
    out.print(":");
    out.print(email);
    out.print(":");
    out.print(password);
    out.println("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
  }
}
```

I want if String email != end in @gmail.com or @yahoo.com ect. But also require their name to be only numbers and letters.
I also want to require users to have a password over 5 characters but less than 15 while also only allowing letters and numbers. I also Want the username to be over 3 characters and less than 13. while also being only numbers and letters.

Comment: There are ZERO reasons to force the password to be less than 15 chars, DONT DO IT.

Comment: For simple content check, use `indexOf()` or `contains()`. For more complex content check, use `matches()` with a *regular expression* pattern. To check password length, use `length()`. To see all available methods of the `String` class, **read the javadoc**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: This is more do my homework question. Than an actually answer.

Comment: You can also use the `endsWith()` method to make sure it ends with `@...`

Answer (score 0):

1. To check if some email address contains an @ symbol, well, that's easy: `if (!email.contains("@")) System.out.println("Hey, now, emails do at least contain an @, you know!");`
2. To check if a string length is between 5 and 15, let's say inclusive because you weren't specific: `if (passw.length() < 5 || passw.length() > 15) System.out.println("5 to 15 characters please!");` – note, as others have said, limiting password length is dumb. There are reasons to do so <schwarzenegger> but they are all bad</schwarzenegger>. So just don't do that. I assume this is homework. Still annoying to see homework questions posit writing a check which is a common industry dumb move. For more detail read up on password hashing, b-crypt, TOTP, etc.
3. The proper way to do error handling here is to tack `throws Exception` onto your main like so: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { ... }`... at least, for any exception where you have no idea how to handle it (and log it and ignore it is *not* handling an exception properly. If that's all you can reasonably do with it, then don't, and just tack on that throws as instructed).

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications aren't perfectly clear to me, but as I understand them, this code should work:

```
// username should be an alphanumeric string of length 4 to 12.
username.matches("[\\p{Alnum}]{4,12}");
// email should be alphanumeric characters followed by an '@' symbol followed by a domain name.
// The standard domain name specification allows for alphanumeric characters or a hyphen as long as the hyphen doesn't start or end the domain name.
email.matches("[\\p{Alnum}]+@[\\p{Alnum}]+(-[\\p{Alnum}]+)*(\\.[\\p{Alnum}]+(-[\\p{Alnum}]+)*)+");
// password should be an alphanumeric string of length 6 to 14.
password.matches("[\\p{Alnum}]{6,14}");
```